# How to change the build configuration in Fastlane - via gym , build _app or xcodebuild

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, fastlane, fastlane-gym, xcode-archive

[image: Xcode Scheme]We have four build configuration in the scheme - QA, Pre prod, Staging, Releasing  with different BaseUrl, I am just trying to change this build configuration via Fastlane gym command but it fails, bu default it is taking the one which is selected PFA for reference

[when running via Fastlane gym command it is taking the default value in the scheme example - pre-prod](https://ibb.co/7jNgkHj)

```
build_app(workspace: "MyApp.xcworkspace", scheme: "MyApp", include_bitcode: true,export_method:"app-store",configuration: "Staging")

gym(workspace: "Omuni.xcworkspace",scheme: stagingScheme,export_method:"appstore,configuration:"Staging")
```

Comment: For QA -> https://qa-mycompany.com
For Preprod. ->  https://preprod-mycompany.com
For Preprod. ->  https://staging-mycompany.com

Comment: Any code snippet is welcome to  change the build configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and add a separate gym file where you define your gym variables like so:

```
scheme("your scheme")
configuration("your configuration")
output_directory("./fastlane/builds")
include_bitcode(true)
include_symbols(false)
export_xcargs("-allowProvisioningUpdates")
```

and then you would call the gym command without any parameters, but I couldn't help but notice that your " are misplaced, ("appstore,configuration:") perhaps fixing that would do as well